# Get a specific attribute from XML file using Ansible xml module

Tags: xpath, ansible

I have an XML file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>p4v</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>2018.2</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2018.2/1666551</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>2018.2, Copyright 2018 Perforce Software, Inc.</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>application.icns</string>
    <key>P4RevString</key>
    <string>P4V/MACOSX1013X86_64/2018.2/1666551 (2018/05/30)</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <string>True</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>P4V</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>P4VC</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.perforce.p4v</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

How can I get the string `2018.2` for key `CFBundleShortVersionString`?

I have tried something like below but its listing all string values instead of one matching the provided key.

```
 - xml:
      path: /Applications/p4v.app/Contents/Info.plist
      xpath: /plist/dict[starts-with(key,'CFBundleShortVersionString')]/string
      attribute: CFBundleShortVersionString
      content: 'text'
   register: p4v_version
```

I think I am providing the wrong xpath here, but I couldn't find the correct one.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the catch. Its a copy paste error. I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `attribute` here at all, and if there are no other `<dict>`-s, you can leave out the first condition.

```
- xml:
    path: /Applications/p4v.app/Contents/Info.plist
    xpath: /plist/dict/key[.='CFBundleShortVersionString']/following-sibling::*[1]
    content: 'text'
  register: p4v_version
```